# search not returning any results php

Tags: php, search

Cant figure out why my search is not returning any result, do i need to parametrized it ? if so how ? here is my code.

i know my sql connection works as i can able to pull data and display it just cant get the search working.

thanks in advance.

```
<?php

include 'Functions/sqlconnect.php';

$search_sql = "select * from Course where name LIKE '%".$_POST['search_name']."%' or Course_ID LIKE '%".$_POST['search_name']."%'";
$search_query=sqlsrv_query($conn, $search_sql, $params);
if (sqlsrv_num_rows($search_query)!=0) {
    $search_rs=SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC($search_query);
}
?>

<p>Search results</p>
<?php
if (sqlsrv_num_rows($search_query)!=0) {
    do { ?>
<p><?php echo $search_rs['Name']; ?></p>

<?php   } while ($search_rs=SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC($search_query));

} else {
    echo "NO results found";        
}

?>

<form name="form1" method="POST" action="Script1.php">
    Name:
<input type="text" name="search_name" />
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="search" />
</form>
```

Comment: Check your logs. Any PHP errors?

Comment: No errors, everytime i click to search it is giving me no results

Comment: `SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC` is not a function. plz use `sqlsrv_fetch_array($search_query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)`